# FontAwesome 5 - многоцветная иконка

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, fontawesome

[FontAwesome 5](https://fontawesome.com/) предлагает тысячи иконок, созданных с помощью SVG. Таким образом, можно легко раскрасить весь значок с помощью заливки. Но что, если я хочу использовать несколько цветов? Например, учитывая значок [Google](https://fontawesome.com/icons/google?style=brands), я хочу его раскрасить так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [FontAwesome 5 - Multi color icon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52578726/7394871) от участника  [@Eliya Cohen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1860540/eliya-cohen).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/52578726/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Используя градиент для цвета и две иконки, мы можем добиться этого, но это остается хакерским способом, и вам нужно обрабатывать каждый случай (значок + окраска) специально:

```css
.fa-google path{
  fill:url(#grad1);
}
.fa-google + .fa-google path{
  fill:url(#grad2);
}
.icon {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
.fa-google + .fa-google {
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   top:0;
   clip-path: polygon(0% 0%,120% 0%,0% 75%);
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js" ></script>
<svg style="width:0;height:0;">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="30%" x2="50%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#34a853" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#4285f4" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="grad2" x1="0%" y1="30%" x2="50%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#fbbc05" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#ea4335" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div class="icon"> 
<i class="fab fa-google fa-7x"></i>
<i class="fab fa-google fa-7x"></i>
</div>
```

Мы также можем рассмотреть использование `conic-gradient()` с одним значком. Опять же, это характерно для этого конкретного случая:

```css
.fa-google {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49%,#fbbc05 50%) 0 25%/48% 40%,
    linear-gradient(to top    left,transparent 49%,#fbbc05 50%) 0 75%/48% 40%,
  
    linear-gradient(-40deg ,transparent 53%,#ea4335 54%),
    linear-gradient( 45deg ,transparent 46%,#4285f4 48%),
    #34a853;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

/*#fbbc05*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css">

<i class="fab fa-google fa-10x"></i>
<i class="fab fa-google fa-6x"></i>
<i class="fab fa-google fa-3x"></i>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52582440/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>